# Using Java Servlet as a Response Page to an HTML form?

Tags: java, html, servlets

Let's say you have an HTML Online Form where you have to Register to vote:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<form>
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
Address: <input type="text" name="address"><br>
City: <input type="text" name="city"><br>
State: <input type="text" name="state"><br>
Zip: <input type="text" name="zip"><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone"><br>

Affiliation:<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="demo">Democrat<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="green">Green Party<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="liber">Liberterian<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="repub">Republican<br>
<input type="radio" name="affil" value="None">Unafiiliated<br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to make it so when you click submit a Response page that shows the user a summary of what they posted

Example:

First Name: [Value]

Last Name: [Value]
etc.

I want to use Java Servlet to do this. However, while I've programmed in Java before I don't have any experience with Servlets and I'm confused on how to start.

So the main tasks I THINK I have to do are

1.Create a Java file.

2.Use HTTPApplets?

3.Make it so the HTML references the Java file in some way.

4.Have the Java (Servlet) show values based on what's passed in.

As said, I'm just not sure how to start.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: You only need 4th one to show the content you passed via form submit.

Comment: Have you tried to google it. There are a lot of informations how to start with servlets.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the servlet as an entry point of your application (this is server programming, so no applets involved).

Let's say your form gets submitted with POST, so the entry point to your servlet would look like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
```

Here you can check through the `request` object every parameter the user has filled into your form.  For example:

```
String address = request.getParameter("address");
```

Do whatever business logic you need and then send back your answer.  You have some options for that:

You could write HTML straight to your `response.getOutputStream()` method, but we don't want that normally.

Or you can forward your answer to a JSP.  That is a special servlet taking the shape of an HTML template.  Do it by calling `request.getRequestDispatcher("/my_page.jsp").forward(request, response)`.  This will make your application server start executing your JSP.  One way to hand the business logic results to the JSP for its presentation is to use the `request.setAttribute` and `request.getAttribute` methods (since your servlet and your jsp share the `request` object).  For example:

Servlet:

```
request.setAttribute("calculation_result", new Float(324324.45f));
```

JSP

```
<div class="myCSSclass">The result is <%= request.getAttribute("calculation_result") %></div>
```

Here you can find some info about writing JSPs and packaging your web application:

http://www.jsptut.com/

http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-make-war-file-in-eclipse.html